# apk/ipa upload: Appium running on Mac and app on Windows

Tags: macos, selenium, apk, appium, ipa

The Appium server is running on Mac and the application on Windows.

A user is able to upload an `ipa/apk` file from the application. I would like to know if there is a way with Selenium to send an `apk/ipa` file through the capabilities and not only the path?

I saw on the Internet something with `RemoteWebDriver` but I think it's only if we want to upload a file during the test.

```
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("{{url}}:{{port}}/wd/hub"), capabillities);
driver.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Appium is able to download a file from the App Path, so that's ok!